# How to use Sentry with go.uber.org/zap/zapcore logger

Tags: go, logging, sentry, go-zap

I am using [`go.uber.org/zap/zapcore`](https://github.com/uber-go/zap) for logging in my Go app.

```
package logger

import (
    "go.uber.org/zap"
    "go.uber.org/zap/zapcore"
    "log"
)

var l *zap.Logger

func Get() *zap.Logger {
    return l
}

func Init() {
    conf := zap.NewProductionConfig()

    logger, err := conf.Build()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Init logger failed", err)
    }
    l = logger
}
```

I also have Sentry project and use `github.com/getsentry/raven-go`.

I want to send logs at `error` level and above to Sentry.

For example when logging at `info` level with `logger.Info()` I want to just log them as usual, but in case of `error` or `fatal` logs I need send these messages to Sentry. How can I achieve that?

Comment: `github.com/getsentry/raven-go` is obsolete, and should no longer be used on new projects. Instead use [the new Sentry SDK](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-go).

Comment: ok, i have changed the library, but my question was not about it

Comment: @Viktor maybe because `Init()` should be `init()`

Answer (score 2):

The answer is you should use zap wrapper for adding hooks then you have to use the function of logger which is called WithOptions

```
sentryOptions := zap.WrapCore(func(core zapcore.Core) zapcore.Core {
    return zapcore.RegisterHooks(core, func(entry zapcore.Entry) error {
        // your logic here
    })
})

logger.WithOptions(sentryOptions)
```

Answer (score 2):

The following will capture the message and send it to the sentry when an error level is detected, with customized error line number and message.

```
err := sentry.Init(sentry.ClientOptions{Dsn: "http://~~~~~"})
if err != nil {
    log.fatal("Sentry Error Setup ::", err.Error())
}

logger, _ := zap.NewDevelopment(zap.Hooks(func(entry zapcore.Entry) error {
    if entry.Level == zapcore.ErrorLevel {
        defer sentry.Flush(2 * time.Second)
        sentry.CaptureMessage(fmt.Sprintf("%s, Line No: %d :: %s", entry.Caller.File, entry.Caller.Line, entry.Message))
    }
    return nil
}))

sugar := logger.Sugar()
```